# Thymeleaf Variables

Tags: html, thymeleaf

Is there a way to tell Thymeleaf that if any of the fields have errors, display the error message?

I'm currently listing them out individually like this:

```
<div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('password')}" th:errors="*{password}" class="validation-message alert alert-danger" role="alert"></div>
<div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('lastName')}" th:errors="*{lastName}" class="validation-message alert alert-danger" role="alert"></div>
<div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('firstName')}" th:errors="*{firstName}" class="validation-message alert alert-danger" role="alert"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#all-errors

Should be able to do something like:

```
<div th:each="err : ${#fields.errors('*')}" class="validation-message alert alert-danger" role="alert" th:text="${err}" />
```